# Can I use episode help envelope when receiving it late & problem receiving texts while playing

Tags: candy-crush-saga

1. I received a "help envelope" from a friend to help me pass on to another episode (the one beginning with level 201) By the time I had gotten it, I had already started 201. Is there anything else I can use the "help mail" for?  It only says that she sent help to pass to episode.
2. While I'm playing candy crush, I can't receive any text messages. Not just the notification, but the message itself isn't received at all on my phone. The  phone sending the message shows that I got it. But I don't even know I missed a message until someone asks me later why I didn't answer. Any help?  I'm using an Android 2 LG.

Answer (score 1):

For the candy crush issue, it won't work for any other episode unlock. Even if you click it, it will just disappear and not do anything.

For your second issue I recommend taking a look here: http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/326644-not-getting-text-message-notifications.html

The main point I want to draw from this is the sms settings for Google hangout. If you have this app, disable the sms settings and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are asking 2 questions. I will answer the one related to Candy Crush more as I have no idea the settings on your phone. I have never had issues with text messages and Candy Crush.

The help mail is only useful for the level in the message. So if you got the help mail late (as in you already started the level or beyond) then it is useless. You can hit accept for that mail, it just won't do anything